# How to find majority in percentage of a list and print corresponding message

Tags: python

So the program is meant to take a list of names and consecutive scores in list form and find majority in percentage form and deliver a corresponding message. When i tried it only gives error int and str can't return function.
eg ("really have a lot in common (>90%)!")

My attempt:

```
from collections import Counter
name=["AAAAA   4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5",
      "BBB     5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2",
      "K       4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1"]

name2=["AAAAA   4 2 1 2 4 2 4 4 5 2 2 1 5 2 4 3 1 1 3 3 5",
       "BBB     5 2 1 2 4 5 4 4 1 2 2 2 4 4 4 3 1 2 3 3 2",
       "CCCCCC  4 2 2 2 3 5 2 1 2 2 1 2 4 3 2 3 4 4 3 3 5",
       "DDDD    2 2 5 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 5 2 2 5 5 1 1 3 2",
       "FFFFFF  5 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 5 1 4 2 2 3 5 1 3 1 4",
       "GGGG    5 2 1 2 1 2 2 5 2 2 2 1 5 2 2 2 1 4 3 4 3",
       "HHH     4 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 4 2 1 2 5 4 3 4 4",
       "II      4 2 1 2 2 1 2 5 1 2 1 2 5 2 2 3 3 1 3 1 2",
       "JJJ    5 2 5 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 4 2 2 2 5 2 3 2 1",
       "K       4 1 2 1 2 1 2 5 1 1 1 1 4 2 2 1 5 1 3 4 1",
       "LLLL    5 2 2 2 2 5 2 1 1 2 1 2 5 3 2 1 3 2 1 5 5",
       "MMMM    4 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 5 2 4 2 2 3 5 1 1 1 5",
       "NNNN    5 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 5 2 2 2 3 3 2 3 2"]
def name(votes):
    vote_count = Counter(votes)
    top_two = vote_count.most_common(2)
    if len(top_two)>1 and top_two[0][1] == top_two[1][1]:
        print("really have a lot in common!")
    return top_two[0][0]
```

Comment: what do votes denote here?

Comment: votes in this case denotes the list of names with numbers,

Comment: Could you please add the exact error message that you are getting when you run the code?

Comment: You have a list called `name` and a function called `name`: one of these needs to be renamed.

Comment: I see, renamed name in function to vote and inside bracket as name